# Import JavaScript prototype extension

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

I found (on this site) a cool little prototype extension function for cleaning up numbers, and now want to use this in a library that I can then import as needed. I see how to import defined functions but not prototype extensions.

file: SomeLib.js

```js
"use strict";
Number.prototype.round = function(places) {
    return +(Math.round(this + "e+" + places)  + "e-" + places);
}
function foo() {
    console.log("doing SomeLib.foo()");
}
export default { round, foo }
```

file: SomeImporter.js

```
"use strict";
import somelib from "./SomeLib.js"; 
somelib.foo();   // outputs 'doing SomeLib.foo()'
var someNum = 1.2345;
console.log(someNum.round(2)); // outputs 'Uncaught ReferenceError: round is not defined'
```

How can I import the 'Number.prototype.round' function in another file?

Comment: `import 'whatever';` is the way to import a module just for side effects.

Comment: I'm trying to compartmentalize the round() function so I can easily reference and use it in other files without having to add it at the top of each file. Are you saying that my importing method prohibits this? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Importing that file, anywhere on the page, modifies the *global Number.prototype*. It will work in all of your files executed after that. That being said, *this is a terrible idea and never ever modify prototypes you didn't create*.

Comment: Notice that this `round` method is actually broken and does not work for very small or very large numbers. Do not use it.

Comment: Good to know it breaks and returns 'NaN'. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: This seems to work as expected:
Number.prototype.round = function(places) {return this.toFixed(places) * 1;}

Comment: I would suggest a small edit.
`Number.prototype.round = Number.prototype.round ||  function(places) ...`

As you are adjusting the global namespace, at least if the name is there already you will only break your own code and not other code in libraries you might be relying on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why someNum.round() would throw an error even when the round is already defined in the prototype of Number in file imported. (Number.prototype.round in someLib.js)

Now, Since you have returned round which is not defined anywhere in someLib.js
You can actually pass the reference of Number.prototype.round as below.

```
export default { round: Number.prototype.round, foo }
```

Then either you use it directly as

```
SomeLib.round.call(someNum, 2)
```

Or you can set the prototype of Number in this file.

Although not sure, why the already defined Number prototype didn't work.

Comment: Defining the export as you did above allows the someNum.round(2) to work. Thanks.